# How to integrate $\int_{C} \frac{z^2}{(z^4 +1)}$ where $C$ is $|z + i| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am attempting to do this using  Cauchy's integral theorem and formula. However I am unable to conclude if a singularity exists at all for me to apply any of those two techniques or any other theorem.

Comment: Hint: \begin{align}(z^4+1)&=(z^2-i)(z^2+i)\\&=(z+i^{1/2})(z-i^{1/2})(z+(-i)^{1/2})(z-(-i)^{1/2})\\\end{align}using the principal branch of the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)
$$\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}=
\frac{1}{2(z^2+i)}+\frac{1}{2(z^2-i)}=\\
\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\cdot\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(z-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}}-
\frac{1}{4\cdot\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(z+\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+
\frac{1}{4\cdot\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(z-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-
\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\cdot\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(z+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}}$$
Given $\left|\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}+i\right|<1$ and $\left|-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}+i\right|<1$, only the values in red fall inside $|z+i|=1$ circle.
Using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)
$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)}dz$$
where $f(z)=1$
$$\int\limits_{|z+i|=1}\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}dz=
\int\limits_{|z+i|=1}\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\cdot\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(z-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}}dz-\int\limits_{|z+i|=1}\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\cdot\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(z+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}}dz=\\
\frac{2\pi i}{4\cdot\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}}-\frac{2\pi i}{4\cdot\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}}=
\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt{2}\cdot(1-i)}-\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt{2}\cdot(1+i)}=\\
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{i}{1-i}-\frac{i}{1+i}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able to figure as to why only the red highlighted terms falls inside the region. As in why the second last term containing $z - \frac{1+i}{√2}$ not inside

Comment: Simply because $\left|\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}+i\right|>1$, you can check that. Just checking, have you done geometry using complex numbers?

Comment: I am new to it. Can you please tell how these partial fractions can be obtained? I only know the elementary partial fractions for real indefinite integrals

Comment: @MathLearner the answer contains a link to Wikipedia, explaining the topic, with examples. The constants here are just complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the function 
$$
f(z)= \frac{z^2}{z^4+1}
$$
is meromorphic, so that the only singularities are the simple poles at the roots of the polynomial $z^4+1$:
$$
z_i=e^{\frac{2k+1}4\pi i},\quad k=0\dots3.
$$
The method of choice for computation of such integrals is the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). Two poles (with positive imaginary part) are outside the integration contour and two others are inside it. So:
$$
\int_Cf(z)dz=2\pi i\left[\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),e^\frac{5\pi i}4\right)+\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),e^\frac{7\pi i}4\right)\right]=-\frac\pi{\sqrt2}.
$$

Comment: Why "two other poles lie exactly on the curve"? E.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%281-i%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2Bi%7C

Comment: @rtybase You are correct. Thank you for catching this!